# GetMessage() function is calling itself infinitely (not coming out of loop)

Tags: getmessage

I am implementing similar type of thing- I have some message box in the else part of the code below..what I get on debugging is that - I have same message box again and again and it doesn't end (which makes my program crash and I need to restart my laptop)..Is there any solution for it? I am using MFC application and creating a button on window explorer's preview pane. Every thing is fine but this is the problem that once if I enter in the loop below I am not able to come out (I mean there is some thing in DispatchMessage or TranslateMessage which calls this function again and again)..I couldn't find whats that ??

the code is as follow-

```
while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
//Onee message box here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i found that when i return true; in this loop the control will come out of the loop(but its not in good approach) **but** this getmessage was not useful for me infact when i reomved it my program was working fine. In its presence it was having infinite loop.
Because i created the dialog using CreateDialogParam() and then DialogProc is called through this CreateDialogParam()  and then i used WM_Commnands to handle the message received according to the application and i feel no use of this getmessage (please point anyone if i am wrong)